# tikzposter and Hebrew support

Tags: hebrew, tikzposter

I am trying to create a poster in Hebrew.

And I am stumbling into the following problem, for some reason, it just fails to compile (`xelatex`) even the simplest code.

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait]{tikzposter}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
 
\begin{document}
    
        טקסט בעברית
\end{document}
```

However, an article class does compile correctly, so I suppose the problem

> ! Package polyglossia Error: The current latin font TimesNewRoman(0)
> does not c ontain the "Hebrew" script! (polyglossia)
> Please define \hebrewfont with \newfontfamily comm and.

is strictly connected to the `tikzposter` class.

How can I overcome the *missing* script?

I'm using Windows MikTex; start of output contains

```
XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (MiKTeX 22.1)
```

Comment: I will add a workaround for (myself) future: you can use \includegraphics, and standaloned hebrew text as an image, that could be pushed where text is expected. Dirty and requires manual adjustments, but works.